# How can i use case when and between in HQL

Tags: java, hql

I would like fetch `ProjectTemplate` between startDate and endDate. in some cases the endDate may be null in that case i would like to set currentDate as endDate. this is my query

```
 session.createQuery("from ProjectTemplate where :currentDate between startDate AND case when endDate is null then :currentDate else endDate ")
                        .setDate("currentDate", new Date())
                        .list();
```

it produce an error

```
antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting "end", found 'null'
```

Comment: It says you have to.close.your case statement with 'end' keyword